# Clickhouse: Equivalent for calculating window mean with rows preceding current row

Tags: clickhouse

I am struggling to find an alternative for a rolling mean function. The equivalent with a typical window function would be as the below:

```
select avg(sales) over (partition by country order by date rows between 4 preceding and 1 preceding) as rolling_mean_last_4
from country_sales
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

At the moment there are no full-featured window functions support in ClickHouse. Some workarounds are often possible though.

For example, you could try to replace this PARTITION BY with GROUP BY + [groupArray](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/agg_functions/reference/#grouparrayx-grouparraymax_sizex) and then get the desired result using [higher order functions](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/functions/higher_order_functions/). If row count reduction of GROUP BY is unacceptable, then you'll have to find a proper way to JOIN it back to original table.

Sounds cumbersome, but might work under favourable circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from [version 21.4](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/window-functions/) added the *full* support of window-functions. At this moment it was marked as an *experimental feature*.

```sql
SELECT
    date,
    country,
    sales,
    avg(sales) OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY date ASC ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS rolling_mean_last_4
FROM 
(
    /* Emulate the test dataset. */
    SELECT
        toDateTime('2010-01-01') + number AS date,
        toInt32(number / 8) AS country,
        number AS sales
    FROM numbers(32)
)
SETTINGS allow_experimental_window_functions = 1

/*
┌────────────────date─┬─country─┬─sales─┬─rolling_mean_last_4─┐
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:00 │       0 │     0 │                 nan │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:01 │       0 │     1 │                   0 │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:02 │       0 │     2 │                 0.5 │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:03 │       0 │     3 │                   1 │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:04 │       0 │     4 │                 1.5 │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:05 │       0 │     5 │                 2.5 │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:06 │       0 │     6 │                 3.5 │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:07 │       0 │     7 │                 4.5 │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:08 │       1 │     8 │                 nan │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:09 │       1 │     9 │                   8 │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:10 │       1 │    10 │                 8.5 │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:11 │       1 │    11 │                   9 │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:12 │       1 │    12 │                 9.5 │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:13 │       1 │    13 │                10.5 │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:14 │       1 │    14 │                11.5 │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:15 │       1 │    15 │                12.5 │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:16 │       2 │    16 │                 nan │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:17 │       2 │    17 │                  16 │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:18 │       2 │    18 │                16.5 │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:19 │       2 │    19 │                  17 │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:20 │       2 │    20 │                17.5 │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:21 │       2 │    21 │                18.5 │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:22 │       2 │    22 │                19.5 │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:23 │       2 │    23 │                20.5 │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:24 │       3 │    24 │                 nan │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:25 │       3 │    25 │                  24 │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:26 │       3 │    26 │                24.5 │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:27 │       3 │    27 │                  25 │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:28 │       3 │    28 │                25.5 │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:29 │       3 │    29 │                26.5 │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:30 │       3 │    30 │                27.5 │
│ 2010-01-01 00:00:31 │       3 │    31 │                28.5 │
└─────────────────────┴─────────┴───────┴─────────────────────┘
*/
```

See https://altinity.com/blog/clickhouse-window-functions-current-state-of-the-art.